# How to add dynamic row for a custom field in magento2 admin form?

Tags: magento, magento2.2

I am trying to add a button/link at bellow of by Department button so that i can add more rows of department. Please refer the screenshot.

[image]

My ui_components look like below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">chanz_user_form.user_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">chanz_user_form.user_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">chanz_user_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Chanz\User\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Chanz\User\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Chanz\User\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\SaveButton</item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">Chanz\User\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="user_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Chanz\User\Model\User\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">user_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">user_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">user_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" path="*/*/save" xsi:type="url"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="General">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">More Product Links</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="dept">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Department</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">dept</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">dept</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>

                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

What change I have to do more to achieve above or can you guide me how to proceed.

Comment: do you have any solution? I have same require now :(( please helppp